# Creating a casual leave field in MS Access

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have created an access database (Access 2007) to store monthly report data of teachers.

It has a form to input monthly report data consisting of name, department, teaching hours etc.

I want to add a field to store information about casual leaves taken in the month.  Suppose a teacher takes 4 casual leaves on 1st, 7th, 16th and 25th in a month how do I make provision on the form to record all four dates in the database?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that solved my problem.  How many such subforms can be added to the main form?  Is there any limit to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create a child table for the casual leave dates and then add a subform to your existing form. For more information on subforms see

[Create a form that contains a subform (a one-to-many form)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-HA010098674.aspx)